# MAX & MIN virtual column value of joined tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a `products` table (id, name) and a related `products_prices` table (id, product_id, value). Each product can have multiple prices. I'm trying to make a query that will list all products with a max and min price from all existing prices for each product, but with no luck. Something like that:

| id | name | price_min | price_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product 1 | 100 | 1000 |
| 2 | Product 2 | 200 | 2000 |

Need help...

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`!

Comment: You begin from using the two aggregate functions `MIN` and `MAX` on the price field. Then add some more fields in the `SELECT` and see that the DBMS complains about a `GROUP BY` clause. Following up the error carefully, you understand that you need to put the non-aggregated (selected) fields in the `GROUP BY` clause. And once you do it, you're already done with this problem.

Comment: Join the two tables then use `MAX(price)` and `MIN(price)` with `GROUP BY products.id`

Comment: @lemon As long as the non-aggregated fields are functionally dependent on the grouped field you don't need to add them to `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using `group by` and aggregate functions `min()` and `max()` :

```
select p.id, p.name, min(value) as price_min, max(value) as price_max
from products p
inner join products_prices pr on pr.product_id = p.id
group by p.id, p.name
```

If you want to list products that do not yet have a price, you may use `left join`:

```
select p.id, p.name, min(value) as price_min, max(value) as price_max
from products p
left join products_prices pr on pr.product_id = p.id
group by p.id, p.name
```